# Excel Vba Prompt user for folder then create worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to prompt user to choose a folder and then continue on with my code to create a new sheet if a folder is chosen, but if user cancels the prompt, then exit sub and don't continue on with the code.
Below is what i have tried.

It is able to show "Please select a folder" whenever i press cancel, however even when i choose a folder, it shows "please select a folder" and stops.

Can anyone please help me with this issue, i have been trying all types of ways, and this best that i can do.

```
Sub selectfolder_createnewsheet
Dim basePath As String
            basePath = BrowseForFolder("C:\")
            On Error GoTo errhandler
errhandler:
            MsgBox "Please Select a Folder"
            Exit Sub

            Dim wks As Worksheet
            Set wks = CreateOutputSheet(ActiveWorkbook)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this so that if user presses cancel, then that is also handled.

```
Sub selectfolder_createnewsheet()
    Dim basePath As Variant
    basePath = BrowseForFolder("C:\")

    If basePath = False Then
        MsgBox "Nothing Selected. Aborting", vbInformation, "No Folder Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = CreateOutputSheet(ActiveWorkbook)
End Sub

Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    '
    '
    '
End Function
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, i tried using this                                                                  `Dim basePath As Variant
    basePath = BrowseForFolder("C:\")

    If basePath = False Then
        MsgBox "Nothing Selected. Aborting", vbInformation, "No Folder Selected"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If basePath = True Then
        
            Dim wks As Worksheet
            Set wks = CreateOutputSheet(ActiveWorkbook)`                                         but somehow it doesn't lead on to continue creating the worksheet.

Comment: What does `CreateOutputSheet()` have?

Comment: i am actually trying to get if a user cancels the prompt, then exit sub, but if user selects a folder, then carry on with the creating of worksheet. sorry if i am not clear. `CreateOutputSheet()` is just creating of a worksheet. However afterwards i do have some more coding going on

Comment: its ok i have removed the `If basePath = True` and now it works, Thanks!